# Handling expired oAuth token in asp.net mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, oauth-2.0, action-filter, authorize

I created a custom filter class which inherit `ActionFilterAttribute`

the method looks like below

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //my custom code
}
```

and my controller looks like below

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Get")]
[Authorize]
[Filters.AuthorizeLogin()]
public List<BusinessEntities.Admin.Role> Get(Dictionary<string, string> Parameters)
{
    //My api call
}
```

but the problem is whenever my token got expired my custom function (`OnActionExecuting`) did not execute,

I want to execute my custom function even after my token got expired.

and should I use `[Authorize]` filter when using `[Filters.AuthorizeLogin()]` filter in my api controller.

Comment: At the OAuth level when a token expires, a refresher token need to be requested, how that's implement with asp.net MVC is specific to the platform in terms of what specific decorators is required  (good explanation with diagrams, https://code-maze.com/using-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-authentication/ )

Comment: @mzm yes, I agree, in my application I used to validate the token from the front end and then request for the new refreshtoken by calling `/token` api from jQuery with `grant_type of refresh_token`, but now I am trying to shift this into server side, that's why I created the above filter

Comment: can you please help me to find the overload method to update refreshtoken

Comment: look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938342/how-to-update-token-using-refresh-token-in-mvc-client-application